# What does triple-single-quote mean in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have seen lots of uses of single and double-quotes in bash, as well as backtick-quotes, but have never seen what follows. What is the meaning of the transcript below, which seems to show that triple-single-quoting is recognized as meaningful by bash and further seems to show that single quotes inside this thing also have special meaning, enabling interpolation? I have found no documentation of this.

```
$ Q=test
$ echo '$Q'                      # <== I know, this doesn't work...
$Q                               # <== ...and so it doesn't. 
$ echo '''$Q'''                  # <== Don't know what this could mean.
$Q                               # <== OK, nothing special?
$ echo ''' "$Q" '''              # <== Try a double-quote??
 "$Q"                            # <== Hmm... OK, nothing.
$ echo ''' '$Q' '''              # <== Try a single-quote?
 test                            # <== Wow, it did interpolate!?
$ echo '''                         
> '''                            # <== Continuation! Proving bash  
                                 #     thinks this is an opening 
                                 #     quote of some kind.
$ bash --version                 # <== FYI,  version info
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: wrt `triple-single-quoting is recognized as meaningful by bash` - **no, it's not**. Two single quotes enclose a literal string or script. That is all. Now re-read your examples with that in mind and I'm sure you can figure out the associated behavior. In fact just remove every contiguous pair of ticks (`''`) and you'll see exactly the same output as you do now because `''` is just a string with no characters in it.

Comment: OK, thank God. I thought one of these examples may prove that it actually *is* a thing, but I know it's like a figment of the imagination, and in -- I guess all -- the examples you can just say it's an empty string followed by a variable. I actually saw code written this way which is why I asked.

Comment: You may be confusing it with `'\''` which IS something useful - it's one way to get a literal `'` in the middle of a `'`-delimited string or script, e.g. `echo 'foo'\''bar'`

Comment: @cdarke I didn't say backslash had any special meaning inside single quotes (it does but you can't escape a 3rd `'` with it) I said in reference to `'\''` that `it's one way to get a literal ' in the middle of a '-delimited string or script` because it's breaking you out of the quotes to let the shell interpret `\'`. Try the code I posted.

Comment: @cdarke You are reading something that simply isn't there into what I clearly said and even gave an example of.

Comment: @EdMorton, that's not right.  You can't escape a `'` inside of a single quoted string.  Maybe you're thinking of `$'\''`?  Or you are saying this usage: `'hello '\'' there'`?

Comment: @Adrian It's been 4 years so I don't recall the context and whatever comments I was replying to have apparently been deleted but whatever it was I definitely wasn't saying you can escape a `'` inside a single quoted string. I'll delete my final 2 comments above in a few minutes to avoid confusing anyone else with whatever that was about.

Comment: @EdMorton, so you're saying the latter then.

Comment: @Adrian Looks like it given [I said in reference to `'\''` that...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978911/what-does-triple-single-quote-mean-in-bash?noredirect=1#comment98613065_55978911)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no “triple quote” ... for example `''' '$Q' '''` is the concatenation of several strings ... `''`, `' '`, `$Q`, `' '` and `''`.  Consider each of the others in the same way.

Comment: Right, right. OK, in a way that's good, though in a way I was hoping bash had some new, fancy quoting I was unaware of, and they had started emulating other languages in this regard.

Comment: @user62177541 You can always just go and read the manual to learn everything about quoting, there aren't a lot of secrets hidden for people to accidentally bump into ;)

Comment: that's so weird! I remember reading somewhere about triple quoting to use unescaped text, then a single to escape and use shell variables at will... and I've been using it for a while without trouble. After reading this answer I thought of trying to substitute all my triples for singles... and everything keeps working. Why would someone claim triple were special in the first place? Internet is full of weird.

Comment: @user62177541, one can only add new, fancy meanings to things that POSIX doesn't already assign a standard-defined meaning to. To make triple quotes behave as anything different from a balanced pair + an extra single quote would mean the single quotes would need to stop having their existing standard-mandated meaning; bash tries to be a superset of the POSIX sh standard (almost; `echo` breaks it a little), so it doesn't/can't do that.